# "Original design by"

Tags: writing

I have a question.
I downloaded a template from Internet. "James" created it (author: James).
I edited this template and do fundamental change.
Now I want add my name to the info box.
What should I write there? (for example I should write "Original design by James, Edited by ME")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this template in any sort of public domain or licensed/distributed on some other terms that allow for modification *and* distribution? If so, then the wording you suggest would be ok, although I would say "Original*ly* design*ed* by James, Edited by YOU" or "Based on original design by James, edited and updated by YOU".